# Preventing Timeout (H12 error) on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

So I'm using Heroku to host a simple script, which runs whenever a specific page is loaded. The script takes longer than 30 seconds to run, which Heroku returns as an H12 error - Request Timeout (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#router). I can't use a background process for this task, as I'm using its run time as a loading screen for the user. I know the process will still complete, but I want a 200 code to be spent when the script finishes.

Is there a way to send a single byte every, say, 20 seconds, so that the request doesn't time-out, and will stop whenever the script finishes? (a response from the heroku page will start a rolling 55-second window preventing timeout). Do I have to run another process simultaneously to check if the longer process is finished, sending a kind of 'heartbeat' to the requesting page, letting it know the process is still running - and preventing heroku from timing out? I'm extremely new to rails, any and all help is appreciated!